# I have an error installing express JS on node

Tags: node.js, express

I got an error installing express. I know what the problem is and how to fix it, but wondering if there is a better way.

This is the error from the terminal:

```
{
  "name": "express",
npm ERR! also called "express". Did you name your project the same

npm ERR! as the dependency you're installing?

npm ERR!

npm ERR! For more information, see:

npm ERR!     <https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install#limitations-of-npms-install-algorithm>

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     C:\Users\Jay\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-10-17T21_48_55_418Z-debug.log
```

I named my folder 'express' and that is causing the error. Now if I just manually change the "name" in the object of  "package.json", would that still work in the future? or should I delete the folder and start again and name it 'express2' or something like that?

Here is a screenshot I uploaded:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlPi8.jpg

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

this happens when you name your project folder with the same name as one of your packages, 
you need to rename your  project folder to a different name, 
and you don't need to delete your project, you can just change the folder name and rename the name from package.json